# How to insert the arraylist in Android sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist, insert

I have  set of `ArrayList` like `Arrays[]={A,B,C,D,E,F}`.How to store this `ArrayList` in android `sqlite database`?

any example code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142285/saving-arraylist-in-sqlite-database-in-android

Answer (score 2):

**how about** :

```
foreach ($array as array)

{  
insert into table (column) values ($array)
}
```