# sql search for a number into a BLOB (list of numbers)

Tags: java, search, sqlite, blob

I've stored an ArrayList of longs (ID's) into a Blob column.
(followed question: [BLOB vs. VARCHAR for storing arrays in a MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106548/blob-vs-varchar-for-storing-arrays-in-a-mysql-table/3107250#3107250))

That works, but now I've a problem: how can I search into that BLOB?

Imagine I've stored this numbers into the BLOB: 1,2,3,4
And what I want to do is:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE blob_column CONTAINS 3
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I once came across this article...http://blog.sbw.be/2006/09/13/oracle-search-inside-blob-content/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is "No, it's not possible".  Your BLOB contains a serialised java object - and the database knows nothing about it's implementation.

When designing a database, you should always think about how you will need to access the data.  In your case, you would be much better off having a separate table, which would contain your ID's from the list in separate rows.  Then you could simply join that table into your query.

Comment: ok, I can change the implementation without problems.
Thanks!